# Migrate users from one Rails app to another, both using Devise, while maintaining passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have fully rebuilt a new Rails app but I need to copy the users over from the old app. Both apps use Devise, but I am not sure how to safely copy the encrypted password and have it work on the new app. Thanks.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but you may want to look into cookies and session management.

Comment: connect the previous database to newly created app.

Comment: The new app has a reasonably different schema, I just need the old email and passwords to stay the same, so I cannot just copy the database.

Comment: Write a `script` to write the `User` table values into a `xml/csv` file. Then use that file and `seed` the file values to your newly created app.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I plan to do, more or less, but the question is how do I migrate them so the users have the same passwords?

Comment: `migration` will only generate the table attributes. In your `csv` file there are users info. (e.g. `email`, `encrypted_password`). So, populate the table with that file. Simple.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't simply copy over an encrypted password right, isn't that generated by a certain amount of meta information on its creation? If I just create a new record with and hand it the old encrypted password, this wouldn't just work with the same password would it?

Answer (score 4):

This is a relatively old topic, but I recently had a similar issue when migrating users from an app to another, both using Devise as auth system.

As discussed above, a valid option is to extract the auth-related fields (email and encrypted_password) from the previous model and insert them in the new one. You'll just have to make sure that you skip the Devise validation steps when populating the new database, otherwise it will require you to provide a valid password.

Therefore this should work :

```
user = User.new(email: 'existing@email.com', encrypted_password: 'existing_password_hash')
user.save(validate: false)
```

If you have a test user with a known password, you can test the results with :

```
user.valid_password?('my_known_password')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: isn't this however dependent on encryption keys? One password hash with one key is a different value than with another.  Between secrets.yml  credentials.yml.enc and devise's own potential encryption `config.secret_key` (the initializer talks of "confirmation, reset password and unlock tokens" *not password encryption*) ... there's a lot to get thrown off here.  How did you process through that?

Comment: I honestly don't recall all the steps I went through back then, but I believe that this worked for existing passwords because :
1) Devise has been using the same password encryption strategy for a few years
2) This strategy is using the first chars of the encrypted value as the salt, so it doesn't rely on an external key
This is a detailed article that explains this in details : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-does-devise-keep-your-passwords-safe-d367f6e816eb/

Comment: Devise also uses pepper from the class so it may differ at the other app